# Input and Output Impedance of a SAW Filter

Tags: filter, inductor, impedance, gps, impedance-matching

I am reading the datasheet of a SAW Filter [B39162B4348P810](https://en.rf360jv.com/inf/40/ds/ae/B4348.pdf). The datasheet doesn't say much about impedance of `Input` and `Output` port. However, on page `5`, it considers Terminating source and load impedance for the specifications.

It says:

> Temperature range for specification: T = –40 ˚C to +105 ˚C
>
> Terminating source impedance: ZS = 50 Ω
>
> Terminating load impedance: ZL = 50 Ω || 8.2 nH

Shall I consider to add an inductor of `8.2nH` value in parallel at the output port?

Comment: Given this is 1,600MHz, the equivalent Cout is about 1.2pF so as to resonate with 0.008 microHenry (8 nanoHenry). This will be very vulnerable to PCB capacitance.

Comment: Cout is the output impedance of the OUTPUT pin? I think you are saying that the capacitance of output pin will dependent on layout and hence, the output series inductance required to cancel it out will also vary?